# code-prettify não funciona com código linear (uma única linha)

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando a biblioteca do Google para formatar código: 
[Google code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)

Ele funciona muito bem em quase todos os casos, porém como meu texto vem em uma única string, não funciona tão bem.

**Ele funciona bem para:**

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**E não funciona para:**

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

Meu exemplo no JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/3qpwtcoy/8/

Tentei utilizar vários plugins JavaScript para formatar, que no meu caso é padrão XML e não consegui sucesso em nenhum.

Comment: Só uma dúvida: parece que o problema é de indentação. Por que vc não pode indentar o código manualmente?

Comment: pq esse código que vem linear, vem de um database, claramente se eu pudesse já teria resolvido, mas não tenho acesso a esse código inline, então eu preciso achar algum plugin q faça essa identação

Comment: Olhando o código no JSFiddle, é sempre essa tag `<property>` ou pode vir qualquer código?

Comment: @Sam, acredito que sim, mas não posso ter certeza(acredito q 99% das vezes sim), o melhor seria formatar sem saber se vem ou não.

Comment: Blz. Eu só que ria saber pq estou tentando fazer um indentador e pra não perder tempo essa informação era necessária, porque se fosse só uma tag seria bem mais fácil. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz um indentador do zero que funcionou no seu exemplo do JSFiddle e em alguns outros testes que fiz.

Funciona da seguinte forma:

Deixe a tag `<xmp>` inicialmente vazia e crie logo após ela uma div oculta e coloque o código linear que vem do banco dentro dessa div:

```
<div id="fonte" style="display: none;">código aqui</div>
```

O código irá percorrer todos os nós dentro da div e montar um array de objetos `tags = []`, para pegar a tag do elemento ou o nó de texto, que são duas coisas diferentes. É preciso distinguir uma coisa da outra para poder montar a indentação corretamente.

Em seguida ele percorre a array de objetos criando um novo HTML na ordem dos nós com quebras de linhas (`\n`) para cada nó, e joga esse novo HTML dentro da div, substituindo o que estava lá. As tags do novo HTML vão todas sem fechamento, porém o navegador fecha todas automaticamente.

Depois ele pega o novo HTML da div e joga pra dentro do `<xmp>`, porém a última linha irá ficar linear com todos fechamentos automáticos gerados pelo navegador. Aí é preciso tratar isso. Irá pegar essa linha e quebrar em array (`last_str.match(/<.+?>/g)`).

Depois basta percorrer essa array adicionando novas linhas ao `<xmp>` dinamicamente com `document.createElement()`, ao mesmo tempo atribuindo as classes nas `<li>` de forma sequencial (se não o componente não reconhece) que vai de `L0` a `L9`.

Mas para isso funcionar, é preciso usar o callback do componente adicionado ao final da URL a string `&callback=iniciar` (onde `iniciar` é o método da função do callback. Você pode dar o nome que quiser em vez de `iniciar`). Esse callback é chamado pela sintaxe:

```
window.exports = { 
   iniciar: function(){

    // código aqui

   }
}
```

A função é executada após o componente ter renderizado o código.

Agora vamos ver funcionando:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var xmp = document.getElementById("XMlHtml"),
   code = document.getElementById("fonte"),
   tags = [],
   tab = "   ", // espaços de tabulação
   tabr = 0;

   nos(code);
   function nos(node){
       for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++){
         var child = node.childNodes[i];
         no(child); nos(child);
       }
   }
   
   function no(e){
      var html = e.nodeType != 3 ? e.outerHTML.match(/^<.+?>/)[0] : null;
      tags.push({ no: html, txt: e.nodeValue });
   }

   var nhtml = '';
   for(var x=0; x<tags.length; x++){
      var no = tags[x].no;
      if(x != 0 && tags[x-1].no) tabr++;
      if(!no) no = tags[x].txt;
      nhtml += tab.repeat(tabr)+no+"\n";
   }
   
   code.innerHTML = nhtml;
   xmp.innerHTML = code.innerHTML;
   
   window.exports = { 
      iniciar: function(){
         var linhas = xmp.querySelectorAll("li"),
         last = linhas[linhas.length-1],
         classe = Number(last.className.replace("L", "")),
         last_str = last.textContent,
         ltags = last_str.match(/<.+?>/g);
         
         for(var x=0; x<ltags.length; x++){

            tabr--;

            if(x == 0){
               if(tabr == 0) tabr++;
               last.querySelector("span").textContent = tab.repeat(tabr)+ltags[0];
            }else{
               classe = classe < 9 ? classe+1 : 0;
               if(tabr < 0) tabr = 0;
               var nli = document.createElement("li");
               nli.setAttribute("class", "L"+classe);
               var span = document.createElement("span");
               span.setAttribute("class", "tag");
               var tabula = document.createTextNode(tab.repeat(tabr));
               span.appendChild(tabula);
               span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ltags[x]));
               nli.appendChild(span);
               xmp.querySelector("ol").appendChild(nli);
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?callback=iniciar"></script>
<?prettify lang=xml?>
<xmp class="prettyprint linenums:4" id="XMlHtml"></xmp>
<div id="fonte" style="display: none;"><properties><property key="expression">from CodigoOcorrencia couch in {[left] =&gt; DefaultIfEmpty()}</property><property key="EventId"><structure type=""><property key="Id">20500</property><property key="Name">Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning</property></structure></property><property key="SourceContext">Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query</property><property key="Scope"><sequence><item>Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor</item></sequence></property><property key="SetorErro">MVC</property></properties></div>
```

> Coloquei todo o código dentro do evento `DOMContentLoaded` para
>   restringir o escopo das variáveis e evitar possíveis conflitos com
>   outras variáveis que você possa estar usando em outro código ou
>   script.

Note também que você pode definir a largura da tabulação pela variável `var tab = "   "`, que no caso acima, coloquei com 3 espaços.

Comment: quem sabe, sabe! quem não sabe vai no CTRL+C...obrigado, vou testar e já qualifico

Comment: Dá uma testada. Se der algum bug a gente verifica.